# Homepage template / queries

Tags: templating

I might be over-engineering this a bit, but I'm looking for a clean way to set up my homepage, for as few database queries and maintaining a DRY setup. The homepage is:

- Hero introduction

  - Fields in a homepage single.
- News & Events

  - Simple blog-like query

And then the two parts I'm confused about. Both of these are pulled from other singles.

- About Us summary
- Membership info

Is it fine to just query these pages individually? It feels so over the top to do something like

```
{% set aboutQuery = craft.entries().section('about') %}
{% set aboutPage = aboutQuery.all() %}
{% for page in aboutPage %}
  <h1>{{ page.title }}</h2>
  <p>{{ page.summary }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm sure this is a fairly common setup, so I just want to know what other people do in cases like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it feels over the top, cause you could simplify your small request to something like this:

```
{% for page in craft.entries.section('about').all() %}
<h1>{{ page.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ page.summary }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Or, if you just want to get the title and the summary of that one single - you could archieve this via:

```
{% set aboutPage = craft.entries.section('about').one() %}
<h1>{{ aboutPage.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ aboutPage.summary }}</p>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for simplifying it for me!